# Finding height of a pyramid , thus finding the volume

Tags: volume

The picture below shows a pyramid PQRT is cut from a corner of a cube whose side is 16cm. If MP = DQ = 9 cm and BR = 8cm , find the volume of the pyramid PQRT

[image]

I found that

PQ = 9.89949 cm

PR = 10.63 cm

QR = 10.63 cm

And area PQR = 46.6 cm^2

Now I'm stuck on how to find the height of the triangular pyramid ... Can I get help ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*HINT*: You don't have to use $\triangle PQR$ as the base. Instead, take $\triangle PTQ$ as the base; the height of the pyramid is then simply $TR$. You will definitely be able to find the solution with this.

(This is more formally a tetrahedron, which can have any of the four triangular sides as its base.)